# Looping through matched values in awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terraform

I am trying to parse the input file using bash and extract values from 'variable' to '}' , however I am not sure how to loop over each matched value and generate the expected output. any help is appreciated.

test.sh:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
        
 file="./test.tf"
 output="$(awk '/variable/,/}/'  $file)"
 echo "$output
```

test.tf:

```
 variable "policy_name1" {
      description = "abc xyz"
      type        = string
      default = [
        test1,
        test2,
      ]
    }
    
    variable "policy_name2" {
      description = "aaa xyz"
      type        = bool
      default     = false
    }
```

Expected output:

```
"policyname1","abc xyz","test1,test2"
"policy_name2","aaa xyz","false"
```

Comment: Add `./test.tf` to your question.

Comment: Why does the file look like broken JSON?

Comment: it's terraform.

Comment: Isn't it better to parse/modify terraform format with terraform specific software and make text/json/csv etc?

Comment: The above sample file is not correct terraform input. The type of "policy_name1" (string) is inconsistent with the default value  (list(string)).

Comment: add actual output to question please

Answer (score 1):

Terraform input files follow the HCL configuration language form (see https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/hcl2/hclsyntax/spec.md).

The language has support for blocks, conditional, etc. It is not possible to parse those files correctly using the line-oriented awk script. You might get more mileage by using the 'terraform show -json' output. Alternatively, trying setting the env var `TF_LOG` with `export TF_LOG=trace`, and reviewing the output