# sed Pattern to Insert Comma after a character

Tags: bash, sed

Add comma after closing bracket `}` using bash.

Using

```
sed 's/variable/&,/g;s/,$//'
```

adds comma after `variable`, however,

```
sed 's/}/&,/g;s/,$//'
```

doesn't work.

Input:

```
 variable "policy_name1" {
      description = "abc xyz"
      type        = string
      default = [
        "test1"
        "test2"
      ]
    }
    variable "policy_name2" {
      description = "abc xyz"
      type        = bool
      default     = false
    }
```

Output:

```
variable "policy_name1" {
      description = "abc xyz"
      type        = string
      default = [
        "test1"
        "test2"
      ]
    },
    variable "policy_name2" {
      description = "abc xyz"
      type        = bool
      default     = false
    }
```

Comment: @F.Hauri Right, I was thinking about `sed -E`/`sed -r` behaviour!

Comment: You have already opened a question containing the same sample file, and you want to parse it and extract values. Just in case you think that you have to prepare this file for parsing (I think it 'd be a good idea) adding that comma there does not seem to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948922/looping-through-matched-values-in-awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILENAME="test.tf"
COUNT=`wc -l $FILENAME | awk '{ print $1 }'`
COUNT=`expr $COUNT - 1`

sed "1,$COUNT s/}/},/" "$FILENAME"
```

I have provided a bash script so that we can avoid the last line in a right way. This script will append a comma whenever it finds an ending curly bracket ( } ) except for when it is last line.

Comment: this works but I dont want to use the count variable and its ok to add , in the last line. I just want to  append a comma whenever it finds an ending curly bracket ( } )  - how should i modify this sed command in that case.

Comment: Then just use, `sed s/}/},/ test.tf`

Comment: The above command will simply replace ending curly bracket ( } ) with an ending curly bracket and a comma ( }, )

Answer (score 4):

### [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) Add a comma after curly bracket, but not on last line:

```
sed -e '$!s/^ \{4\}}$/&,/'
```

- `$!s/` Not on last line replace
- `^ \{4\}}$` lines begin with 4 space, followed and terminated by `}`
- `/&,/` by matched content, followed by `,`.

Will render:

```
    variable "policy_name1" {
    description = "abc xyz"
        type    = array
        default = [
            "test1"
            "test2"
        ]
    },
    variable "policy_name2" {
    description = "abc xyz"
        type        = bool
        default     = false
    },
    variable "policy_name3" {
    description = "simple test string..."
        type        = int
        default     = 42
    }
```

### More complex: Add comma on each lines but not on last for each block:

```
sed -e ':a;N;/[^{\[(,] *\n/{/\n[ \o11]*[]})]/!s/\n/,\n/};P;D;$!ba'
```

Could render:

```
    variable "policy_name1" {
    description = "abc xyz",
        type    = array,
        default = [
            "test1",
            "test2"
        ]
    },
    variable "policy_name2" {
    description = "abc xyz",
        type        = bool,
        default     = false
    },
    variable "policy_name3" {
    description = "simple test string...",
        type        = int,
        default     = 42
    }
```

- `:a;` Label `"a"` for furthen *branch*
- `N;` Merge with next line
- `/[^{\[(,] *\n/` If buffer contain other than comma or open bracket, followed by *newline*
- `{` then do block:

  - `/\n[ \o11]*[]})]/!` If NOT buffer contain newline followed by space and other then close bracket
  - `s/\n/,\n/` then place a comma before *newline*
  - `};` end of block
- `P;` print buffer up to *newline*
- `D;` delete buffer up to *newline*
- `$!ba` If not on last line, branch to `"a"`